# I ran into a clipping issue and I don't understand why

Tags: ios, iphone, opengl-es, powervr-sgx

I notice it when viewing from a specific angle but if I move a little or change the direction the camera is pointing then it'll go back to normal.  I'm not really sure even where to start with this one.

I only render faces exposed to air and I dont have culling enabled in opengl.

Anyone have any thoughts on what could cause this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Edit:
I went through and captured the Model-View-Projection matrix from an OpenGL frame and tested the center point of the clipped area.  And according to my calculations that point should be in the view frustum.  So I'm still confused.  The table shows my work.  I got the test for being in the view frustum from this solution: [How to check if an object lies outside the clipping volume in OpenGL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301085/how-to-check-if-an-object-lies-outside-the-clipping-volume-in-opengl)

Data used to create the perspective matrix:

```
fovy: 70.0f, aspect: 960.0f/640.0f, near: 0.1f, far: 30.0f
```

Data used to create the lookAt matrix:

```
eye: 29.8548 67.6202 37.6915 center: 30.8396 67.4502 37.7284 up: 0.169884 0.985443 0.00636673
```

Comment: Is the right side only two faces?  You can see the bottom tri near you and what looks like a bit of the top tri.  Assuming that's not a third triangle then it looks like some kind of z artifact, not the whole triangle being culled

Comment: Yes each face is made of two triangles.  Any tips on how to investigate a z artifact?  It is the first time I've heard that term.

Comment: Maybe it's your perspective matrix, where you're too close to the triangle.  Change the zNear maybe?  Oh, and is it just me, or does that look like minecraft?

Comment: I don't believe the perspective matrix is the problem.  I ran some calculations using the model-view-projection matrix and by my calculations that area that is clipped should be in the view frustum.

Comment: Have you tried to increase the `far` value? 30 doesn't seem to me very 'far' compared to (30,67,38). I know that MVP*point is for sure inside your frustum, but still that looks like a plane cutting away a portion of your render.